# How to get two versions of Python to coexist within a virtualenv?

Tags: python, macos, bash, pip

In order to not alter the default python installation, I have a virtualenv set up that automatically runs on startup. I've also set up my profile so that unless a virtualenv is running, pip will not run. I've been using python2.x up to now, and have now installed python3 via homebrew. When I attempt to install a new package via pip3, I get the following error: `Could not find an activated virtualenv (required).`. However, when I check for the existence of a virtual env by checking the $VIRTUAL_ENV variable, it tells me that a virtual env is in fact running: `-bash: /Users/me/virtualenvs/r: is a directory`. Do I need to create separate instances of virtualenvs for each version of python? Why will one of my versions of python recognize the virtualenv, while the other will not?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have two separate virtualenvs?

Comment: Would it? What would be the pros and cons? I was under the impression the two versions of python exist fairly independently.

Comment: Having different virtualenv will mean that you have fully independent versions of python running. THe only disadvantage is that you will use up a bit more disk space.

Comment: What would be the point of having a `virtualenv` that does not isolate? I mean, if you really want something like that, why bother using `virtualenv` at all? You could simply locally install many python versions into a directory and add the directory to your `PATH`. But that's really messy and because of that `virtualenv` was invented/introduced in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

All your virtualenvs are stored in a directory -- `/Users/me/virtualenvs` in your case. If you go there, you'll notice that it executes totally separate python interpreters in each virtualenv. For example, this is a freshly created virtualenv:

[image]

I'd imagine that running pip3 while on the python2.7 virtualenv wouldn't work for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are two different kinds of virtualenvs, one of which is compatible with python2 and one of which is compatible with python3. I'm not sure whether there is a way to get one that is compatible with both, but I went ahead and created a new virtualenv using python 3 (`python3 -m venv myPython3Env`), and have been able to successfully use that.